# CSS: style="position: fixed" causes document to "ignore" <div> and overlays content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set a div to `position: fixed` in order to maintain a top fixed header. The problem is that the moment that you set a div to `postition: fixed;` or `position: absolute;` it's like that div is no longer considered when spacing the content and the content that used to be just below that content is now overlayed. One way to fix this is to wrap in a div and set a fixed margin or height, but what is the margin is not fixed?

When the browser is resized, the height of the fixed div increases, meaning that the fixed height/margin that I implemented no longer suffices. Please have a look at [http://littegiant.myfreelancer.co.za](http://littlegiant.myfreelancer.co.za). You will see that I added a bunch of `<br>` in order to assert a fixed-height differential so that the content does not overlap, but that this is no longer enough when the browser width (and thus the header height) changes. I have seen that this is a problem when used the Bootstrap, `navbar-fixed-top` as well. There HAS to be a way to assing a fixed div and still keep it in mind when populating the other content and scrolling...

**Original Width:**

[image]

**Adjusted Width:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There HAS to be a way to assing a fixed div and still keep it in mind
>   when populating the other content and scrolling...

There is not. What you are observing is (and always has been) part of the CSS spec. `absolute` or `fixed` positioned elements are taken out of the normal document flow meaning non-child elements are not affected by them.

Comment: The part about the CSS spec is correct: +1 for emphasising document flow. However, the OP could - for example - use JS to check the calculated height of the navbar and adjust the content accordingly. Personally, I would opt for using media queries to adjust the top padding of the content.

Comment: The JS solution (as you probably recognize) is a bad way of doing things. I'd use media queries, too, but I'd start by using them to change the layout of my header at certain breakpoints to make sure it's a known height and doesn't become any taller, making it easy to just say 'padding-top: Xpx' on your body.

Comment: yes, that's exactly the same approach I'd take as well. The JS method is not advisable; I only mention it for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use conditional CSS to change the positioning of the overlapping navbar if the window is resized or if the device has a lower resolution.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#topHeader{
    position:relative !important;
}
```

This appears to give things some room to breathe. You will need to make your slider responsive though, it seems to be dipping off screen.

I hope this helps.